# Ionic 3 storage cannot read inside of forEach

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I can not use the storage inside the forEach.

But outside of forEach, the storage works perfectly.

My code is below:

tmp.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tmp',
  templateUrl: 'tmp.html',
})
export class TmpPage {

  url: string = "http://www.myurl.com:8282/ionic/php/";

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    public storage: Storage,
    public http: Http
  ){
    this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
      res.forEach(function(valor) {
        console.log('login_sucesso:'+valor.login_sucesso);
        this.storage.set('login_sucesso', valor.login_sucesso);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

My console is:

```
login_sucesso:OK
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'storage' of undefined
    at tmp.ts:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (tmp.ts:30)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:242)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:189)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
```

Printscreen of my console
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QOLG.jpg)

What I need to do exactly, is to fetch PHP information and pass to storage.

Can someone help me?

*** SOLVED ***
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161108/10609587

```
res.forEach((valor) => {
    console.log('login_sucesso:'+valor.login_sucesso);
    this.storage.set('login_sucesso', valor.login_sucesso);
  });
```

Comment: Hey Leandro, can you mark answer bt BRass as solved then?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making the adjustment below, to use a "fat-arrow" function?  Seems like you may be losing your `this` context.

```
  res.forEach((valor) => {
    console.log('login_sucesso:'+valor.login_sucesso);
    this.storage.set('login_sucesso', valor.login_sucesso);
  });
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that worked.  If this is the correct answer can you please mark it as the answer for others who stumble upon this?